# Simplify ajax function when checking JSON data

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have JSON with some data (text, images, links). If there's a specific ID on a page, add the images, text, and links related to the ID in a container. I was just wondering if there's a better way to code the AJAX function or even set up the JSON considering that the JSON might have more data.

Thanks ahead for the insight!

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cirya",
  success: function(data) {
    Data = data;

    $.each(Data, function(key, val) {
      // check if #uniqueID3 is in the DOM
      if (some condition) {
        relCat3 = val['uniqueID3']['relatedCategory'];

        //Create grid of rooms
        $.each(relCat3, function(k, v) {
          $('.container').append('<div class="grid_4 box1"><img src="' + v['relCat1Image'] + '" alt=""><a href="' + v['relCat1URL'] + '">' + v['relCat1Name'] + '</a></div> <div class="grid_4 box2"><img src="' + v['relCat2Image'] + '" alt=""><a href="' + v['relCat2URL'] + '">' + v['relCat2Name'] + '</a></div> <div class="grid_4 box3"><img src="' + v['relCat3Image'] + '" alt=""><a href="' + v['relCat3URL'] + '">' + v['relCat3Name'] + '</a></div> <div class="grid_4 box4"><img src="' + v['relCat4Image'] + '" alt=""><a href="' + v['relCat4URL'] + '">' + v['relCat4Name'] + '</a></div>');
        });

        // check if #uniqueID9 is in the DOM    
      } else(some condition) {
        relCat9 = val['uniqueID9']['relatedCategory'];

        //Create grid of rooms
        $.each(relCat9, function(k, v) {
          $('.container').append('<div class="grid_4 box1"><img src="' + v['relCat1Image'] + '" alt=""><a href="' + v['relCat1URL'] + '">' + v['relCat1Name'] + '</a></div> <div class="grid_4 box2"><img src="' + v['relCat2Image'] + '" alt=""><a href="' + v['relCat2URL'] + '">' + v['relCat2Name'] + '</a></div> <div class="grid_4 box3"><img src="' + v['relCat3Image'] + '" alt=""><a href="' + v['relCat3URL'] + '">' + v['relCat3Name'] + '</a></div> <div class="grid_4 box4"><img src="' + v['relCat4Image'] + '" alt=""><a href="' + v['relCat4URL'] + '">' + v['relCat4Name'] + '</a></div>');
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```js
// json...
[{
  "uniqueID3": {
    "relatedCategory": [{
      "relCat1Name": "bed skirts",
      "relCat1URL": "http://www.google.com",
      "relCat1Image": "https://dummyimage.com/146/000/fff.jpg&text=3-image-1",
      "relCat2Name": "duvet covers",
      "relCat2URL": "http://www.google.com",
      "relCat2Image": "https://dummyimage.com/146/000/fff.jpg&text=3-image-2",
      "relCat3Name": "throw pillows",
      "relCat3URL": "http://www.google.com",
      "relCat3Image": "https://dummyimage.com/146/000/fff.jpg&text=3-image-3",
      "relCat4Name": "comforters, quilts and bedspreads",
      "relCat4URL": "http://www.google.com",
      "relCat4Image": "https://dummyimage.com/146/000/fff.jpg&text=3-image-4"
    }]
  },
  "uniqueID9": {
    "relatedCategory": [{
      "relCat1Name": "shams",
      "relCat1URL": "http://www.google.com",
      "relCat1Image": "https://dummyimage.com/146/000/fff.jpg&text=9-image-1",
      "relCat2Name": "down and down alternatives",
      "relCat2URL": "http://www.google.com",
      "relCat2Image": "https://dummyimage.com/146/000/fff.jpg&text=9-image-2",
      "relCat3Name": "bed skirts",
      "relCat3URL": "http://www.google.com",
      "relCat3Image": "https://dummyimage.com/146/000/fff.jpg&text=9-image-3",
      "relCat4Name": "throw pillows",
      "relCat4URL": "http://www.google.com",
      "relCat4Image": "https://dummyimage.com/146/000/fff.jpg&text=9-image-4"
    }]
  }
}]
```

Comment: Do you have control of the JSON format as that's horrendous. Why it's returning `relCatNName`, `relCatNURL` and `relCatNImage` is beyond me; they should be properties of objects in an array with consistent keys.

Comment: I can suggest to change the JSON but yea, it can be updated